# I need to get the string value split in different variables individualy

Tags: c#, string, methods

I want to get the values from the string individualy and store it in variables so i can check if they are valid or not.

```cs
Int32 count = 1;
string ip = ("198.170.60.90");
char[] separator = { '.' };
string[] address = ip.Split(separator,count,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string x in address)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I am trying write a program that checks the valibity of an IP adress and my mentor told me to search for the String.Split method.

Comment: Your code seems to do that just fine, so what is your question?

Comment: Yea, i want to have different variables for each part of the string.

Comment: This is a [XY problem - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You ask about splitting a string because you think that it will solve your problem, where in fact you want to know how to validate an IP address. The question should be *"How do I validate an IP address?"*. E.g., @raBinn gives a valid answer that does not involve string splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path:

1. Split the string.
2. Make sure you get expected number of parts.
3. Iterate the parts to check them individually.

In code, that would be:

```
private bool IsValid(string ipAddress)
{
    // Split the string parts by the character '.'.
    string[] ipAddressParts = ipAddress.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Make sure the ip address has four parts
    if (ipAddressParts.Length != 4)
    {            
        return false; 
    }
    
    // Iterate the ip address parts to check them individually
    foreach (string part in ipAddressParts)
    {
        // Make sure the part is an integer
        if (int.TryParse(part, out int numericPart))
        {
            // Make sure the integer part is between 0-255
            if (numericPart < 0 || numericPart > 255)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
bool isValid = IsValid("198.170.60.90"); // true

bool isValid = IsValid("198...60.90"); // false

bool isValid = IsValid("198.170.5a.90"); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you try check if IP is valid?

```
System.Net.IPAddress _ip = null;    
bool isValidIp = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.1.33", out _ip);
```

Comment: You could use a discard: `System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.1.33", out _)`

Answer (score 0):

It is way simpler than you made it.

Please check this code snippet:

```
string ip = "198.170.60.90";
var splittedString = ip.Split('.');
foreach(var element in splittedString){
  Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

It produces this output:

```
198  
170  
60  
90
```

The parameter that you have used in method invocation, precisely `count = 1` , means that you expect that the string will be split into *exactly* 1 element – so it will not be split.
If you want to stay with it just increase the count value to the number of splitted elements are you expecting.

Comment: Added two spaces after each line to insert line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would be better off doing this with the `IPAddress` class in `System.Net`:

```
string ip = "192.170.60.90";
if (IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out var ipAddress)) // parse the ip
{
    foreach (byte b in ipAddress.GetAddressBytes()) // go through each octet
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b); // write the octet
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP not valid.");
}
```

Output:

```
192
170
60
90
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OWB16513)

Docs:

- [GetAddressBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes?view=net-5.0)
- [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-5.0)